# How to compare two modelled time courses using the log likelihood ratio test in R?

Tags: r, time-series, likelihood

I have two different species in three replicates of which I measured 24 metrics during five days. I'm trying to decide when there is a significant difference between the two species for a specific metric in the course of these 5 days.

To minimise the number of tests I thought it was a good idea to generate a linear model for each metric and species and then compare them using a likelihood ratio test, thereby avoiding a test for each day. I used this before for gene expression studies ([described here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19119428)). Example data is shown below, usually there is no clear correlation between the species.

However when I tried to implement it in R, I can't seem to capture the uncertainty of the values at a certain day into account. In addition the *lrtest* from the *lmtest* package always gives the same value (highly significant). I feel like I hit a brick wall when it comes to comparing models and even whether this is the way to go.

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lmtest)

#Create some data which looks like the one I'm working on
vals = c(0.96,0.85,1.07,0.60,0.65,1.17,0.77,0.53,1.02,0.39,0.36,0.42)
days = c("Day0","Day0","Day0","Day1","Day1","Day1","Day2","Day2","Day2","Day5","Day5","Day5")

data = data.frame(Days=days, Values=vals)
datab = data.frame(Days=days, Values=(vals*1.000001))

#Get models
modelA <- lm(data$Values ~ data$Days)
modelB <- lm(datab$Values ~ datab$Days)

#make the tests
lrtest(modelA, modelB)

#Just the visualisation code below!
#fit predictions for visualisation
library(ggplot2)
predicted_A <- data.frame(exp_predict = predict(modelA, data), Days=data$Days)
predicted_A <- unique(predicted_A)

predicted_B <- data.frame(exp_predict = predict(modelB, datab), Days=datab$Days)
predicted_B <- unique(predicted_B)

#Check fit in a plot
ggplot() + geom_point(data = data, aes(x = Days, y = Values),color='black') + 
  geom_line(color='black',data = predicted_A, aes(x=Days, y=exp_predict, group = 1)) + 
  geom_point(data = datab, aes(x = Days, y = Values),color='blue') + 
  geom_line(color='blue',data = predicted_B, aes(x=Days, y=exp_predict, group = 1))
```

Output:

```
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: data$Values ~ data$Days
Model 2: datab$Values ~ datab$Days
  #Df LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1   5 4.2616                         
2   5 2.5845  0 3.3543  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Just to clarify, I'm not looking for correlation between the two plant species for that metric. I want to know which metrics are significantly different and worth a closer look. If there already is an implementation in R or Python that would help.

Comment: Something is wrong here. Those two fits should produce identical inference. The "significance" of the LRT is spurious. I don't replicate the output running your code. Strangely, while the logLiks are the same for the two models (which is obvious), the p-value for the LR test is statistically significant. And one can't do a 0-df test. It makes no sense. I think the authors should be made aware of that: the p should be 1 comparing identical models.

Comment: I had a feeling it was down to the package, are there any other implementations of the LR test you are aware of?

Comment: `lrtest` is for comparing different models fit to the same data. That's not what you are doing here.

Comment: Is there a test to compare models from different datasets? Or if I am using the wrong approach, is there a better test for timeseries?